# git add → git commit. Is this right?

Tags: git

Now I'm placticing Rails-tutorial practice3.1 and 3.2.

There is something I don't understand.

```
<solve first exercise>
    ★★★$ git commit -am "Eliminate repetition (solves exercise 3.1)"
<solve second exercise>
    $ git add -A
    $ git commit -m "Add a Contact page (solves exercise 3.2)"
    $ git push -u origin static-pages-exercises
    $ git checkout master
```

why did not do "git add" on ★★★??
I thought,

---

Actor(worktree)

↓↑　★git add

index(staging area)

↓↓　★git commit

local repository

---

So we can't git commit without git add, 
but we can.

Now I have just tested,

```
$ git commit -m "Add a Contact page (solves exercise 3.2)"
```

It's bad. (Changes not staged for commit)

```
   $ git commit -am "Add a Contact page (solves exercise 3.2)"
```

It's ok. (Add a Contact page (solves exercise 3.2))
...why we can this???

Actually, I dont't know the meaning of option -a....

Please tell me

1)we can git commit without git add?

2)the meaning of `git commit -a`

thanks

Comment: Reading the documentation shouldn't be that difficult, and would be much faster than to write a question here. It's even the first option on the list: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Comment: You are right. Thanks,sixty4bit.

Answer (score 1):

The `-a` flag allows you to add/stage the changed files in the same command as the commit. So using `git commit -am "message"` is the equivalent of `git add -A` followed by `git commit -m "message"`.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit